# How to plot when we have dropdown menu with multiple selections?

Tags: drop-down-menu, callback, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I am pretty new to **dash plotly**. I am trying to create a dropdown menu with multiple selections ON. I have a dataframe with the column names `[‘col1’, ‘col2’, ‘col3’, ‘col4’, ‘col5’]`. I want to plot this dataframe to have `‘col5’` in the `y-axis`, and the rest of the columns in the dropdown menu for the x-axis selection. I want to add these columns to my x-axis when I selected them from the dropdown menu.
I cannot understand what I need to modify to make it work. I checked the published posts but couldn’t figure it out.
I get `“Callback error updating mygraph1.figure”` when I run my code below:

```
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px
from dash.exceptions import PreventUpdate
    
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 5))
df.columns = (['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5'])
    
app = Dash(external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.SUPERHERO])
    
app.layout = dbc.Container([
     dbc.Row([
         dbc.Col([
             dcc.Dropdown(id='mydd1',
                          options=df.columns.values[0:4],
                          multi= True,
                          clearable=True,
                          value=[])
         ], width=4),
     ]),
    
     dbc.Row([
         dbc.Col([
             dcc.Graph(id='mygraph1', figure={})
         ], width=4),
     ])
    
 ], fluid=True)
    
 @app.callback(
     Output('mygraph1', 'figure'),
     Input('mydd1', 'value'),
 )
    
 def update_title(X):
     if X is None:
         raise PreventUpdate
    
     fig1 = px.line(df, x=df[X], y=df['col5'])
     return fig1
    
 if __name__ == "__main__":
     app.run_server(debug = True, port=8055)
```

Comment: Please share minimal dummy data to reproduce your example in your machine and able to help you.

Comment: @Hamzah it can be any dataframe. I updated my post with a random dataframe.

Comment: You can select multiple columns on x-axis and y is the fifth column, right?

Comment: @Hamzah Exactly

Comment: I meant your plot has multiple graphs based on the selection from the dropdown menu, right?

Comment: @Hamzah yes, I want to visualize any of the selections only in 1 figure.

Comment: But how can you draw 4 graphs with one px.line?! I think you need to use go.Scatter to use it in loop.

Comment: I have seen similar plots in plotly using the line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the value of X, it is a list and you cannot use is directly like df[X] because it is invalid synatx in pandas to write df[['col1']].

**Full example:**

```
import dash
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from dash import Dash, html, dcc,dash_table
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

    
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 5))
df.columns = (['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5'])
    
app = dash.Dash(external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.SUPERHERO])
    
app.layout = dbc.Container([
     dbc.Row([
         dbc.Col([
             dcc.Dropdown(id='mydd1',
                          options=df.columns.values[0:4],
                          multi= True,
                          clearable=True,
                          value=[])
         ], width=4),
     ]),
    
     dbc.Row([
         dbc.Col([
             dcc.Graph(id='mygraph1', figure={})
         ], width=4),
     ])
    
 ], fluid=True)
    
@app.callback(
     Output('mygraph1', 'figure'),
     Input('mydd1', 'value'),
 )
    
def update_title(X):
     if X == []:
        return dash.no_update

     fig = go.Figure()
     for idx, col in enumerate(X):
         fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x =df[col] , y =df['col5'], mode ='lines', name = col))

     
     return fig
    

app.run_server(debug=True, use_reloader=False)
```

**Output**

[image]